# How do I import data via code in R (Instead of using the import in the menu bar) from code typed into an R notebook?

Tags: r, readxl

Every time I type in the file name in this case "labelled edited.xlsx" (perfectly - it was copied from the import box when using the import function from the menu into an R notebook), then try to run it, it says 'Error: path does not exist'. However using the import menu works. If I copy and paste the exact same thing from the import box:

`labellededited <- read_excel("labelled edited.xlsx", col_names = TRUE, .name_repair="minimal")`

into the notebook and run it immediately, it works perfectly. However, when I close R, open it again, set the working directory (without changing a single thing in the directory folder so the file names are the same), it returns the error even though absolutely nothing has changed - I just restarted R.

In addition to this, copying the code from the notebook into the import box on the bottom right will import the dataset perfectly, as does copying the line of code into the console. It only happens when I press cmd+enter directly from the notebook.

Any tips on fixing this? I know it's not a big deal, but ideally, i'd like to create a code, set the directory and then just let it run.

Comment: Show your R commands. Maybe you're not including the whole path, which includes the drive letter.

Comment: hi , you can define path by ```setwd('your path') ``` then use code  ```df <- read_excel('filename.xlsx')``` Hope this will help

Comment: @Edward I'm not sure what you mean by show R commands. This is the exact command I am using, I set the working directory once when I open up R then run the code (I only have one drive so I don't think it shows up). If I run it from my notebook file using cmd+enter, it doesn't work. If I copy the exact same code from the notebook into console it works. I would like it to work straight from the notebook instead of having to copy and paste it

Comment: @TusharLad I was unaware you could set a working directory to a specific file, I thought it had to be a folder.

Comment: You cannot. Tushar Lad meant: `setwd("D:/StackOverflow/")` or something similar. Set the working directory to a __directory__ on your computer, preferably to the one where the file is located. And even if you only have one drive, you still have to specify it.

Comment: Hi Edward,yes,where the file is located in local folder in computer.

Comment: @Edward I have done that. I navigate to the file that the folder is located in through the menu bar (no drive shows up as I only have one). I just don't understand why AFTER doing that, running from the notebook using a keyboard shortcut does not work but copying the code directly from the notebook and into the console does. It is literally the exact same thing.

Comment: @codingnewbie. Please show the R command that resulted in the error: __'Error: path does not exist'__.

Comment: I think there is something you are not telling us. I'm not being difficult or anything, I'm just trying to get to the underlying cause. Are you using RStudio? Is the command file saved as an R command (script) file?

Comment: @Edward Here is a screenshot of what happens - working directory has been set. The first returns a error, the second - exact same code allows the import to occur. (i had to change the names of the file but it's the same idea) https://imgur.com/a/An3q9Kx

Comment: I am using Rstudio, the file is saved as .Rmd? All the other commands in the file work perfectly fine. Loading libraries, splitting data etc.

Comment: The first line of code in the screenshot comes from cmd enter. The second line of code in the screenshot comes from copying and pasting. Only the 2nd works for some reason and it is the exact same

Comment: OK. Try saving the file as "something.R" instead of "something.Rmd". Or start a new R Script file, copy the code from the other file, and save it as "something.R". Then try using Ctr+Enter.

Comment: Error: `path` does not exist: ‘transposed edited.xlsx’
3.
stop("`path` does not exist: ", sQuote(path), call. = FALSE)
2.
check_file(path)
1.
read_excel("transposed edited.xlsx", col_names = TRUE, .name_repair = "minimal")

That's the extended 'traceback' error I get

Comment: Yes, or make a brand new .R script file (Ctrl+Shift+N) and copy that one command then use Ctrl + Enter.

Comment: I opened a new script (instead of notebook like I was using earlier), copy and pasted everything over and ran it - it worked! thank you!! Much appreciated. Any chance you know why it wasn't working when using a notebook format?

Comment: RStudio is rather fussy about file types. I don't know how else to explain that. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with RStudio and file types. In order to use the keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+Enter) the commands have to be saved as an R script file. So start a new one (Ctrl+Shift+N) and copy the commands from the .Rmd file, and try again.

Comment: Thank you again! I was so confused because every other command had been working for me in notebook (using the keyboard shortcuts) - only this one was crappy. I'll just start using script from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this i guess,

set working directory using setwd("your Path/") then

library(readxl)

if you want to import xlsx use read_xlsx , if you want to import xls use read_xls

labellededited <- read_xlsx("labelled edited.xlsx",sheet = "select sheet number"(default it will consider as first sheet)

more better way you can keep path inside the code and import the file(if you don't move the file it will import without any error)

labellededited <- read_xlsx("yourpath/labelled edited.xlsx",sheet = "select sheet number")

Hope it helps

Comment: I know how to import a file using the console. My question is that if I have the code in an R notebook, it will not run using cmd+enter (which runs just one line of code). I would like to run it directly from the notebook instead of having to copy and paste it.